# Как сделать проверку if else по определённому шаблону?

Tags: python, aiogram, if, бот

Всем доброй ночи, подскажите как правильно сделать проверку if else, введённого текста пользователем по моему шаблону.

```
    await message.answer(text='Укажите время по примеру ниже\nНапример (с 21:30 24.11.2022 по 21:40 24.11.2022)')
    await state.set_state(registration_of_the_application.first_time_last.state)
    
@dp.message_handler(state=registration_of_the_application.first_time_last)
async def first_time_last(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(first_time_last=message.text)
```

Мне нужно что бы в хендлере:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=registration_of_the_application.first_time_last)
```

Была проверка по шаблону с 21:30 24.11.2022 по 21:40 24.11.2022 где цифры могут быть любые, но порядок записи такой `с   :     .  .      по    :    .  .` (то есть эти символы вместе с(с, по) должны быть в таком порядке, а цифры уже могут быть любые).Помогите пожалуйста реализовать данную проверку, буду благодарен за помощь. P.S: Всем добра!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У message_handler есть аргумент regexp, который работает как text, только ловит регулярное выражение. Регулярное выражение — мини-язык, который позволит тебе искать подстроки в тексте. То есть по какому-то шаблону ты сможешь искать совпадения в своем тексте, строке. В твоем случае самое простое это такое выражение
`pattern=r"^с \d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} по \d{2}:\d{2} \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}$"`
и передать его в `regexp=pattern` Это шаблон без проверки на валидность дней, месяцев и всего прочего. В качестве домашнего задания по регулярным выражениям попробуй написать с проверкой. И вообще советую ознакомиться с регулярками, поскольку эта вещь очень нужная, порешай задачи на эту тему

Пример про аргумент regexp в message_handler: https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/discussions/581

upd. если посмеяться над здравым смыслом, то тебе нужно ловить фиксированный шаблон, а значит можно проверять посимвольно. насколько я помню, в message_handler можно передавать функцию, поэтому можно передать туда

```
def valid_string(s: str) -> bool:
    if s[0] == 'c' and s[2].isdigit() ...
```

это будет даже работать быстрее, поскольку регулярку нужно еще скомпилить

Comment: спасибо за помощь, правда у меня не получается сделать как вы написали но, это уже такое!